# can i iterate through a table in sql without having an id column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, while-loop

Let's say I have a table with two columns (e.g. quarter and year) and I want to create a third column based on the value of these two. Is there a way to iterate the table with a while loop without having or creating an identity column?

Well to give you an example, let's say I have these rows:

```
Quarter    Year    Datetimes  
---------- ------  --------------  
1          2018    null  
2          2018    null  
3          2018    null
```

I want to update the 3rd column and make it:

```
Quarter    Year    Datetimes  
---------- ------  --------------  
1          2018    2018-03-31 00:00:00.000  
2          2018    2018-06-30 00:00:00.000  
3          2018    2018-09-30 00:00:00.000
```

I know how to make the conversion, the formula is this:

```
DATEADD(YEAR, @theYear - 1900, DATEADD(QQ, @TheQuarter, -1)).
```

The problem is that I want to update the table, which means I want to add new information, not just show what the 3rd column would be as an output.

Comment: Why do you want that 3rd column? (When the data is already there, in the two already existing columns.) BTW, SQL Server has computed columns...

Comment: Why iterate at all? And what kind of calculation do you want to perform? SQL Server has many ranking functions like ROW_NUMBER(), RANK, DENSE_RANK, NTILE. You can calculate running sums, averages etc with the `OVER` clause too, eg `SUM(someValue) OVER (Partition by YEAR,Month)` will return the montly total for each year & month

Comment: If you want a running total per month, you can write eg `SUM(someValue) OVER (Partition by YEAR,Month ORDER BY Year,Month,Day ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)`

Comment: If you want to calculate eg the ending date of a month for the year and mont, you could write `select eomonth(datefromparts(YearColumn,MonthColumn,1))`. You wouldn't need a loop. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Well, yes, you can iterate through a table using a cursor without an `id` column.

But that is a really bad idea for a few reasons:

1. You should avoid cursors in general.
2. Your tables should all have defined primary ids.
3. You can probably do what you want using a set-based query.

Answer (score 1):

The `CURSOR` object is specifically designed to iterate through any set of rows, determined by a `SELECT`. Your `SELECT` can be as complex as you want and doesn't required rows to be unique.

The basic syntax is like the following example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dates') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Dates

CREATE TABLE #Dates (
    Month INT,
    Year INT)

INSERT INTO #Dates (
    Month,
    Year)
VALUES
    (1, 2018),
    (5, 2018),
    (10, 2020),
    (10, 2020) -- Repeated value

DECLARE @c_Month INT
DECLARE @c_Year INT

DECLARE DateCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        D.Month,
        D.Year
    FROM
        #Dates AS D
    ORDER BY
        D.Year,
        D.Month

OPEN DateCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM DateCursor INTO 
    @c_Month,
    @c_Year

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SELECT
        Month = @c_Month,
        Year = @c_Year,
        CalculatedColumn = DATEFROMPARTS(@c_Year, @c_Month, 1)

    FETCH NEXT FROM DateCursor INTO 
        @c_Month,
        @c_Year

END

CLOSE DateCursor
DEALLOCATE DateCursor

/*
Results:

    Month       Year        CalculatedColumn
    ----------- ----------- ----------------
    1           2018        2018-01-01

    Month       Year        CalculatedColumn
    ----------- ----------- ----------------
    5           2018        2018-05-01

    Month       Year        CalculatedColumn
    ----------- ----------- ----------------
    10          2020        2020-10-01

    Month       Year        CalculatedColumn
    ----------- ----------- ----------------
    10          2020        2020-10-01

*/
```

That being said, please **refrain from using cursors as much as possible**, as relational databases are designed and optimized to work with sets. Cursors should be your last resort.

**EDIT**: You dont need a cursor at all:

```
UPDATE T SET
    YourColumn = DATEADD(YEAR, T.Year - 1900, DATEADD(QQ, T.Quarter, -1))
FROM
    YourTable AS T
```

Comment: I think this works but I want inside the while loop to update the 3rd column from null to the calculated value for each row